# An interesting system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We have the following system with $a$ and $b$, real numbers:

$
\begin{cases}
ax + y + z = 4 \\
x + 2y + 3z = 6 \\
3x - y - 2z = b \\
\end{cases}
$

Show that $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is a $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the system admits a solution composed by integers.

OK, how do you tackle this?

Comment: A very crude way to solve this would be to eliminate $x$ by the substitution $x=6-3z-2y$

We are left with two equations,

$$(1-2a)y+(1-3a)z=4-6a\tag{1}$$
$$18-7y-11z=b\tag{2}$$

Solve these simultaneous equations.

Comment: @user3105228 Enlighten me why this set of equations is interesting, please.

Comment: It's interesting because of what the probelm ask us to prove! @Sabyasachi, if you solve the system like this, what do you get?

Comment: @user3105228 I have no idea. that is why it was a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Given $a$, let $x$ be any integer you want. The system, $y+z=4-ax$, $2y+3z=6-x$, has a unique solution in integers $y,z$. Now that you have integers $x,y,z$, the third equation makes $b$ an integer.